# Python BS4 define a variable for tags found in string?

Tags: python, loops, variables, beautifulsoup

How to define a variable for tags, aswell pass strings not found exp: Orange.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''[<div>Red </div>, <div>Green </div>, <div>Blue </div>]'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
paints = soup.findAll("div")

for i in range(len(paints)):
    try:
        paints[i].text = "OK"
    except:pass


file = open('C:/Users/Admin/colors.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
file.write('1.'+str(Red)+' 2.'+str(Green)+' 3.'+str(Blue)+' 4.'+str(Orange)+)
file.close()
```

Output Wanted (text document):

1. OK 2. OK 3. OK 4.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a dictionary with {color:OK|NO}

Note/tip -- `use for ... in ...` for looping

```
# iterate using for ... in ...
for paint in paints:
  print(f"found {paint.text}")
```

We want a list with index and OK|NO if found/not eg "1. OK 2. OK 3. OK 4. NO
Assuming we have some list of what we want to find like "Red, Blue, Orange" etc...

```
wanted = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange"] 
html = '''[<div>Red </div>, <div>Green </div>, <div>Blue </div>]'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
paints = [paint.text for paint in soup.findAll("div")] 

# make a dict with [color, OK|NO] 
result = dict()
for paint in wanted: # go through wanted items
  if paint in paints: # check if it was found 
    result[paint] = "OK"
  else: # or not 
    result[paint] = "NO"


print(result)
```

Now we have a dict with {"Blue": "OK", "Orange": "NO" ... etc... }

we can go over the keys/values and index with

```
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(result.items()):
    print(f"{i}. {k} {v}")
```

This will give us output "1. Blue OK 2. Orange NO ... etc